# Configure different versions of the same Grails application

Tags: grails, configuration, servlets

By default Grails uses the following locations to look for config files:

```
"classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
"classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
"file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
"file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"
```

But this leads to conflicts if two (or more) versions of the same application (with the same app name) are runing in the same servlet container. I need this for testing.

How can I use different config files for two Grails applications with the same name in the same servlet container?

Comment: These paths are totally changeable, what if you include the version in the file names plus the appName?

Comment: You can get the application version this way ApplicationHolder.application.metadata['app.version']

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by Externalize Your Grails Configuration.
Here is a good link : [externalize grails configuration](http://phatness.com/2010/03/how-to-externalize-your-grails-configuration/)

I hope this help.